# When creating method parameters should I use built in data types or interfaces? C#

Tags: c#, methods, types, parameters, interface

Which is considered the better practice between the two methods created below? MakeCallV1 is simpler and has less code. MakeCallV2 is open to extension and adheres to SOLID principles.

If V2 is considered better, would it be a good rule of thumb to *not* create methods that use built in data types (string, int, etc)?

```
public class Caller
    {
        public void MakeCallV1(string phoneNumber, string name)
        {
            //Using built-in data type string
        }

        public void MakeCallV2(IContact contact) {
            //Using IContact
            var name = contact.Name;
            var number = contact.PhoneNumber;
            //Make call code
        }
    }


public interface IContact
{
    string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Since `contact` contains no behaviour both will follow SOLID principles. Of course introducig class `Contact` will be more "extensive" solution because you don't need change signature of method when you will add more arguments for contact. Particulary in this case you don't need interface at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If V2 is considered better [not passing primitives], would it be a good rule of thumb to not create methods that use built in data types (string, int, etc)?

If that was a good rule of thumb then the .NET framework and/or many other APIs will not have such methods in them. This obviously is not true so *you cannot simply conclude that passing primitives to methods is not a good idea.*

**How do I decide between creating a method accepting primitives vs custom types?**

Ask yourself this question: *How will clients use my class?* By *client* I mean anyone who will consume your class. To answer that question, you can start by examining how it is used right now.

1. If the parameters are related to each other, then a custom type will be better.
2. If the parameters are not related to each other, then primitives may be a better idea.

Looking at your code, I would go with option 1. Why? Because it seems you are managing contacts; therefore, your client classes will have a type which implements the interface `IContact` and the parameters are related to each other.

**What do you mean parameters are related to each other?**

Consider this method signature:

```
public void MakeCallV1(string phoneNumber, string name)
```

I can basically do this as a client:

```
// company is some object of Company class
var phoneNumber = company.PhoneNumber; 
var name = contact.Name;

MakeCallV1(phoneNumber, name);
```

The arguments I am passing do not belong to the same object, so there is *no relation and they are not related*.

Now consider this method signature:

```
public void MakeCallV2(IContact contact)
```

In this method the client will pass something which implements `IContact` so the properties will belong to the same object and thus are *related*.

**One last point to consider**

If your method accepts primitives, and you decide at a later point your method needs additional inputs, you will need to change your method signature (contract, public interface) and this will have side effects: Your clients will need to change.

Comment: _Ask yourself this question: How will clients use my class?_ - this approach have a name - Test-Driven Development  :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I disagree that the approach is called Test Driven Development. Although, in TDD this may become obvious.

Comment: So it depends on what MakeCall is meant to do. It’s not a case of  “better practice”, one is not better, they are very different methods.

MakeCallV1 needs a name and number to work. It calls a _name and a number_. This information may or may not be related,  MakeCallV1 doesn’t care. 

MakeCallV2 needs a Contact to work. It calls _Contacts_, the name and number are related.

Answer (score 0):

Like always - it depends.

If its just a simple case and logically the method expect two parameters, there's no reason the put them together in an object just for that, let alone creating an interface.

If there is already an object that contain these two parameters, you might consider moving this function to the object itself.

However, there are cases when wrapping parameters together do make sense and that's when the function signature contains too many parameters.
Then, extracting them to a class might be a smart move.